# adding long text to video editor

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Is there a limit for the text in the editor?

I am trying to add a very long text (to scroll, but that's another topic), but when I paste it in the text field (strip?) it is truncated at 511 characters.

Is there a way to overcome this limit?

Comment: This is probably best done in an actual 3d Scene with a regular Text object and superimposed with a scene strip in the video editor

Comment: I agree with DFR, and I am sorry to say that the sequencer doesn’t seem to have much options for this. That’s something I might want to put on rightclickselect.com

Comment: I added https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/796y/

Comment: Thanks, will try the suggested solution. Upvoted the rightclick

Comment: what about adding a second text to video editor? ;)

Comment: The text strip buffer is limited to 512 bytes. And they do not want to change that. 
Yet another failed attempt to improve the text editing of Text Strips: https://developer.blender.org/D10775